# android recyclerview refreshing bug?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use viewpager+fragment+RecyclerView+SwipeRefreshLayout.
as the gif shows when the RecyclerView refreshed, it shows blank and it can be shows after pull up RecyclerView.
Can anyone tell me what's the reason and how to solve the problem?

http://www.sszhe.com/static/images/1.gif

```
    refresh_listview.setHasFixedSize(false);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL);
    refresh_listview.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

...................

try{
        Document doc=Jsoup.parse(htmlstr,GB.site);
        Elements es=doc.select(array.get(3));
        if(es.size()>=1){
            activity.clearOneArray(titleNum);
            adapter.clearDate();
            activity.convertDateForItem(GB.getPubuItem(es,array), titleNum);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    adapter=null;
    adapter=new Dynamic2Adapter(this, activity, titleNum);
    refresh_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    refresh_listview.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(0, activity.subCategoryItems.get(titleNum).size()-1);
    refresh_listview.getLayoutManager().requestLayout();
    refresh_listview.requestLayout();
    refresh_listview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: adapter=null; remove this line

Answer (score 0):

finally, i find out the soultion myself.

in fact when the fragment come back,refresh_listview.getAdapter() will become null.

so it should be a judgment for this.
if null, you should make a new adapter